# SSRS Font Issue -- SSDT 2012

Tags: reporting-services, fonts

I am trying to create a report in SSRS that requires a custom True Type Font.  I have installed the font on Windows and can see it in both MS Word and Excel with no problem; however, it is not showing as an available font inside SSRS.  Is there another place fonts need to be installed for Visual Studio?  I have read that the font will need to be installed on the reporting server, but I'm not able to access inside VS, so I'm not quite there yet with installing it on the server.

Alternatively, maybe it would work if I edited the font in the code?  Has anyone tried this?

Comment: personally, I think custom fonts are a bad idea and will cause you headaches in the future.  You'll need to have it installed on the server (make sure its part of your future migration/update notes), and all of the developers that will ever work on this report will need to have it installed on their local development machine.  If any users exports the report to Word/Excel, they may have issues with it as well.  Just a headache waiting to happen.

Comment: Agreed, but the developers aren't the ones making this particular decision.

Comment: Have your devs change it on the reportviewer page via the css.